# Remove the rows of jTable that have been selected and were saved in a list at same time after press a button

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to remove the rows that are selected after a button is pressed.

That's is my code: I have a column that is a checkbox, then a check if it is checked and add the corresponding line to the list.

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTableLayouts.getModel();

// gets the number of rows that were selected
Public ArrayList<Integer> selectedLines = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int j = 0; j <= jTableLayouts.getModel().getRowCount(); j++) {
    if ((Boolean) jTableLayouts.getModel().getValueAt(j,2)){ //checkbox
          selectedLines.add(jTableLayouts.getSelectedRow());     
        }
         model.removeRow(selectedLines.get(j));           
    }
```

With this code I can remove one by one. Any ideas how I can remove all the lines after a press the button?

**EDIT:** I only need to remove the rows that are marked as true in the checkbox. Example: the rows 0,1,4,5 are marked as true, after that I will add these lines in a list, and then just remove the lines that are on the list at same time after the button is pressed.

Comment: `DefaultTableModel#setRowCount` and pass it `0`

Comment: but i  only need to remove the rows that are marked as true in the checkbox. Example: the rows 0,1,4,5 are marked as true,   after that I will add these lines in a list, and then just remove the lines that are on the list at same time after the button is pressed.

Comment: *"With this code i can remove one by one. Any ideas how i can remove all the lines after a press the button?"* - Take the code you have and put inside an appropriate `ActionListener` registered with your button

Answer (score 0):

As *@MadProgrammer* already commented, you can do this from a button by having the `ActionListener` perform the deletes and add the deleted rows to the list you want.

In this snippet when pressing the button, the checked rows on the left are deleted and added to the table on the right. Check the `createDeleteButton` method for how this is done.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestTableDeleteRows extends JPanel {
    private JTable tblLeft;
    private JTable tblRight;

    public TestTableDeleteRows() {
        initialize();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(600,400);
    }

    private void initialize() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(createHeaderPane(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(createTablePane(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(createDeleteButton(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private JPanel createHeaderPane() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        p.add(new JScrollPane(new JLabel("Source",SwingConstants.CENTER)));
        p.add(new JScrollPane(new JLabel("Deleted",SwingConstants.CENTER)));
        return p;
    }

    private JPanel createTablePane() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        tblLeft = createTable(stdRows);
        tblRight = createTable(new Vector<Vector<Object>>());
        p.add(new JScrollPane(tblLeft));
        p.add(new JScrollPane(tblRight));
        return p;
    }

    private static final int COL_CHECK=0;
    private static final int COL_TEXT=1;
    private static final Vector<Vector<Object>> stdRows;
    private static final Vector<Object> cols; 
    static {
        stdRows = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        for(int i=0;i!=100;++i)
            stdRows.add(new Vector<Object>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{Boolean.FALSE,"This is text line number "+(i+1)})));
        cols = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"Check me","Silly text"}));
    }

    private static JTable createTable(Vector<Vector<Object>> rows) {
        JTable t = new JTable(rows,cols) {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                if(getRowCount()>0)
                    return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
                return super.getColumnClass(column);
            }
        };
        t.getColumnModel().getColumn(COL_CHECK).setPreferredWidth(50);
        t.getColumnModel().getColumn(COL_TEXT).setPreferredWidth(200);
        return t;
    }

    private JButton createDeleteButton() {
        JButton b = new JButton("Delete checked rows");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Vector<Vector<Object>> removedRows = new Vector<>();
                DefaultTableModel modelLeft = (DefaultTableModel) tblLeft.getModel();
                for(int r=0;r!=modelLeft.getRowCount();++r)
                    if((Boolean) modelLeft.getValueAt(r,COL_CHECK)) {
                        removedRows.add((Vector<Object>) modelLeft.getDataVector().get(r));
                        modelLeft.removeRow(r--);
                    }

                DefaultTableModel modelRight = (DefaultTableModel) tblRight.getModel();
                for(Vector<Object> row : removedRows)
                    modelRight.addRow(row);
            }
        });
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Delete checked rows in JTable from button");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setContentPane(new TestTableDeleteRows());
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: A run of the snippet]